# why pointing an int(or any) pointer to a struct doesn't give error

Tags: c, struct

Here is the code which works without any error,

```c
struct Node{
  int data;
  struct Node* next;
}n1;

void main(){
    int *head = NULL;
    head = &n1;
    // more code..
}
```

Isn't it wrong to save a struct's address into an pointer which supposed to save an integer's address. I should have initialized it as `struct Node* head = NULL;`

Is it, that address of anything takes same space to save?(types are all about allocated space, ain't they?)

Comment: Every good compiler should warn about that assignment. Check your compilers warning settings.

Comment: Even more every compiler *must* warn about that assignment.

Comment: Yes, all take the same space and they should. It will not cause any problem to your system, output or program itself, unless you end up messing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a logical error, not a syntax issue. compiler should not produce any error message for this, normally.

Here, you're putting an address `&n1` into a pointer variable `head` which is *syntactically* valid. Compiler has no reason to raise an error. It should [*must*] produce a warning message about the incompatibility of the data types, though.

**Bottom line:** Enable warnings in your compiler and pay heed to the emitted warnings. They are there for a resaon.

Comment: It's true Sourav, but compiler warnings would warn about this if there is no explicit cast.

Comment: @iharob Yes, maybe _warnings_, not ___errors___, right? (unless -Werror)

Comment: Behavior in OP's case (assignment and even dereferencing that pointer) may be well defined, because first member of the struct is `int`. I'm not sure about it, but I'm sure that `struct S {int var;}; struct S *head = (struct S *)&n1;` is well defined.

Comment: @user694733 Oops, sorry. Then C and C++ have different requirements on it; or my information was completely wrong. I deleted that comment.

Comment: @user694733 Me too. Edited the answer.

Comment: The code in the question violates a constraint for simple assignment. A compiler _must_ warn about this and may refuse to compile. So it's like a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

This code is ill-formed. Assignment can only be done between pointers of incompatible type if one of them is `void *`. The compiler must give a diagnostic message

However this is legal (and if your compiler only gives a "warning" for the original code, then perhaps it transforms the code to this and proceeds):

```
head = (int *)&n1;
```

Then you can operate `head` just the same as if you had written `head = &n1.data;`.

There is no alignment problem because a struct is always aligned correctly for its first member. There is no strict-aliasing problem because the lvalue `*head` has type `int` and the data being aliased has effective type `int`; and `int` is compatible with `int`.  (It doesn't matter that one `int` is a struct member and the other isn't).